# How to connect to Polkadot Relay-Chain through the code of moonbeam parachain?

Tags: polkadot-js, relay-chain, moonbeam

I want to connect `polkadot relay` chain but i'm not able to select keys for the `customSpec` generated by the binary of `Moonbeam-Parachain`. The **customSpec** is this->

```json
    {
      "name": "Moonbeam Local Testnet",
      "id": "moonbeam_local",
      "chainType": "Local",
      "bootNodes": [],
      "telemetryEndpoints": null,
      "protocolId": null,
      "properties": {
        "SS58Prefix": 1284,
        "tokenDecimals": 18,
        "tokenSymbol": "GLMR"
      },
      "relayChain": "polkadot-local",
      "paraId": 1000,
      "codeSubstitutes": {},
      "genesis": {
        "runtime": {
          "system": {
            
          },
      "parachainInfo": {
        "parachainId": 1000
      },
      "balances": {
        "balances": [
          [
            "0xf24ff3a9cf04c71dbc94d0b566f7a27b94566cac",
            1298074214633706907132624082305024
          ],
          [
            "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0",
            1298074214633706907132624082305024
          ],
          [
            "0x798d4ba9baf0064ec19eb4f0a1a45785ae9d6dfc",
            1298074214633706907132624082305024
          ],
          [
            "0x773539d4ac0e786233d90a233654ccee26a613d9",
            1298074214633706907132624082305024
          ]
        ]
      },
      "transactionPayment": {
        "multiplier": "8000000000000000000"
      },
      "parachainStaking": {
        "candidates": [
          [
            "0xf24ff3a9cf04c71dbc94d0b566f7a27b94566cac",
            2000000000000000000000000
          ],
          [
            "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0",
            2000000000000000000000000
          ]
        ],
        "delegations": [],
        "inflationConfig": {
          "expect": {
            "min": 10000000000000000000000000,
            "ideal": 20000000000000000000000000,
            "max": 50000000000000000000000000
          },
          "annual": {
            "min": 40000000,
            "ideal": 50000000,
            "max": 50000000
          },
          "round": {
            "min": 26846,
            "ideal": 33396,
            "max": 33396
          }
        },
        "collatorCommission": 200000000,
        "parachainBondReservePercent": 30,
        "blocksPerRound": 1800,
        "numSelectedCandidates": 8
      },
      "authorFilter": {
        "eligibleCount": 50
      },
      "authorMapping": {
        "mappings": [
          [
            "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
            "0xf24ff3a9cf04c71dbc94d0b566f7a27b94566cac"
          ],
          [
            "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
            "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "maintenanceMode": {
        "startInMaintenanceMode": false
      },
      "migrations": null,
      "proxyGenesisCompanion": {
        "proxies": []
      },
      "ethereumChainId": {
        "chainId": 1280
      },
      "evm": {
        "accounts": {
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000005": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000006": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000007": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000009": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000400": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000401": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000402": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000800": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000801": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000802": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000803": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000804": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000805": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000806": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000807": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000808": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000809": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000080a": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000080b": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000080c": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000080d": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000080e": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000080f": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000810": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000811": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000812": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000813": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000814": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000815": {
            "nonce": "0x0",
            "balance": "0x0",
            "storage": {},
            "code": [
              96,
              0,
              96,
              0,
              253
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ethereum": {},
      "democracy": {
        "phantom": null
      },
      "councilCollective": {
        "phantom": null,
        "members": [
          "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0",
          "0x798d4ba9baf0064ec19eb4f0a1a45785ae9d6dfc",
          "0x773539d4ac0e786233d90a233654ccee26a613d9"
        ]
      },
      "techCommitteeCollective": {
        "phantom": null,
        "members": [
          "0xf24ff3a9cf04c71dbc94d0b566f7a27b94566cac",
          "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0"
        ]
      },
      "treasuryCouncilCollective": {
        "phantom": null,
        "members": [
          "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0",
          "0x798d4ba9baf0064ec19eb4f0a1a45785ae9d6dfc",
          "0x773539d4ac0e786233d90a233654ccee26a613d9"
        ]
      },
      "openTechCommitteeCollective": {
        "phantom": null,
        "members": [
          "0xf24ff3a9cf04c71dbc94d0b566f7a27b94566cac",
          "0x3cd0a705a2dc65e5b1e1205896baa2be8a07c6e0"
        ]
      },
      "treasury": null,
      "crowdloanRewards": {
        "fundedAmount": 150000000000000000000000000
      },
      "polkadotXcm": {
        "safeXcmVersion": 3
      }
    }
  
}
```

Which Keys should I insert in the above? And what should i insert in the `Rpc calls` after making `customSpec`?.

Can someone please guide me through this?